# How to use if condition inside an object in react

Tags: reactjs, json, object, axios

I'm trying to pass some data as payload to the api and I'm struggling to put condition inside of the object. I have an object called `payload` and I want to pass it in the api by checking the value of the state called `profession`.

```
const payload ={
  name: registerData.fullname,
  password: registerData.password,
  confirm_password: registerData.confirmPassword,
  email: registerData.email,
  additional_info: {
    profession == "Student" ? (
    universityname: values.universityname,
    course: values.course,
    start_year: values.start_year,
    end_year: values.end_year, ) : 
   (professorUniversity: values.professorUniversity,
    department: values.department,
    organizationName: values.organizationName,
    organizationLocation: values.organizationLocation,
    investorCompany: values.investorCompany,
    investorCompanyWebsite: values.investorCompanyWebsite,
    companyName: values.companyName,
    govtSector: values.govtSector,
    govtDesignation: values.govtDesignation,
    )
  }, 
};
  // I'm passing the payload in the api.
 api.post("some-url/register", payload);
```

as you can see in the top I want to pass the entire key and value if the condition is true. If the   `profession` is not student I don't even pass the `universityname` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a combination of [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
 const payload ={
  name: registerData.fullname,
  password: registerData.password,
  confirm_password: registerData.confirmPassword,
  email: registerData.email,
  additional_info: {
    ...(profession == "Student" ? {
    universityname: values.universityname,
    course: values.course,
    start_year: values.start_year,
    end_year: values.end_year, } : 
    {professorUniversity: values.professorUniversity,
    department: values.department,
    organizationName: values.organizationName,
    organizationLocation: values.organizationLocation,
    investorCompany: values.investorCompany,
    investorCompanyWebsite: values.investorCompanyWebsite,
    companyName: values.companyName,
    govtSector: values.govtSector,
    govtDesignation: values.govtDesignation,
    })
  }, 
};
```

I have explained something similar [here](https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/add-component-prop-based-on-condition-in-reactjs/)

An example:

```js
let car = "BMW";

const result = {

  ...(car === "BMW" ? {
    make: "Germany"
  } : {
    make: "other"
  })

};

console.log(result);
```